# Web Service Method returns 404 error

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am trying to call a web service method. When I am calling it without https:// then its working fine but as I call it with https:// it is returns 404.

I've searched on internet about this and found some of the solution.
But those solution were for calling webservice on https but this is when .svc is not calling at all.

In my case it is calling .svc file successfully but not the method.

Comment: Does the webservice has HTTPS enabled? If not, you should e getting the 404 error.

Comment: What is the webservice you're calling? have you checked the console?

Comment: yes it is. you must be talking about <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" /> and multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  this right?

Comment: @christiandev yes, even it is working on http at this time also. as I change http to https it returns 404 (only method url) not .svc

Comment: Can you share the configuration of the end point?

Comment: @venerik I am sorry I am not allowed to share.